# Does codenameone QR/Barcode scanner work on the simulator?

Tags: codenameone

I am using the [cn1-codescan](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan) library. However, I don't get any action at all when I try it in the simulator? Does it work or not work on the simulator?

Comment: Ok. Not supported on the simulator. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported on the simulator. We could probably provide a UI that lets you input a text value for the callback but we never did that.